# How to get longitude and latitude from address in google map using java script in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, geolocation

Please suggest me the different ways how i get the longitude and latitude from address so that i can pass the value to get the navigation from current location in IONIC Framework.

Till Now I am able to get the lat long from address:

```
address$scope.geocodeAddress = function() {
    var address = document.getElementById('from').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            console.log("latlng-->" + results[0].geometry.location);
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful: ' + status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you are trying to do and show us some code of what you have already tried?

Comment: Hi Dexter , i am trying to get the latitude and longitude from address and pass it to navigate in google native api launching from my ionic app. Till now I have success for getting lat long from address

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML5 Geoloc, it will use Phone GPS.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

There's a lot of ressource to help you out with it like [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, the question is about getting coordinates from an address, not the current location.

Comment: If he wants it from a precise address, he has no choice, he must look up to a public database like Google Places. You can't just guess coords from address, you have to ask someone who recorded it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open Google Maps with directions to a specific address, you don't have to get the latitude and longitude. You can use the `phonegap-launch-navigator-plugin` to launch Google Maps with the address filled in and Google Maps will handle the rest. You can find [documentation](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator) on how to use it here and as a bonus you can also open many other navigation apps.